# Detect duplicate set of IDs in grouped collection

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates, microsoft-dynamics

I have the following classes:

```
public class ExistingProposal
{
    public Guid ProposalIdPK { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public List<ExistingProposalElement> GoldenRecordElements { get; } = new List<ExistingProposalElement>();
}

public class ExistingProposalElement
{
    public Guid ProposalElementIdPK { get; set; }
    public Guid ProposalIdFK { get; set; } // foreignkey referencing ExistingProposal.ProposalIdPK
}
```

This classes are initialized with existing proposals and its elements. The Proposal will have various StatusCode's like "Accepted", "Declined", etc.

While creating new proposals and elements I need to check if there is already a proposal containing the same elements like the new ones

so lets assume the folowing situation:

```
ExistingProposal    ExistingProposalElement
1                   1
                    2
                    3
2                   5
                    6
                    7
```

Now a new proposal needs to be created with elements for example with ID's 5,6 and 7. My check now needs to detect
that there is already a proposal with these ID's.

The new ProposalElement-ID's are contained in a

```
List<Guid> newElements
```

How can I detect that there is already a proposal containing the same ProposalElement-IDs like contained in my List "newElements" and a particular "StatusCode"?

I assume that it will be related to the Linq "All" method or similar, but I'm really stuck with it since I am not really advanced with Linq.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an exact match of elements? For example if you have a new proposal 5,6 and 7 you need a match or should 5 and 6 match or should 5,6 and 8 match? You get the idea.

Comment: I need the exact match...so if existing and new proposal contain the exact same ID's I need a match. If I receive IDs 5,6,7 and there is already an existing proposal with element-Ids 5,6,7 I need to get a true for example

Answer (score 0):

Here are the dummy classes I setup to test this. I set up the two examples you provided and then a new proposal to check that it already exists.

```
var existingProposal1 = new ExistingProposal
{
    Id = 1,
    GoldenRecordElements = new List<ExistingProposalElement>
    {
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 1 },
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 2 },
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 3 },
    }
};

var existingProposal2 = new ExistingProposal
{
    Id = 2,
    GoldenRecordElements = new List<ExistingProposalElement>
    {
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 4 },
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 5 },
        new ExistingProposalElement{ Id = 6 },
    }
};

List<ExistingProposal> existingProposals = new List<ExistingProposal>
{
    existingProposal1,
    existingProposal2
};

var newElements = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

This code should let you know if it already exists.

```
var exists = existingProposals.Any(x => x.GoldenRecordElements
     .Select(y => y.Id)
     .Intersect(newElements).Count() == x.GoldenRecordElements.Count());
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for you reply. But still I miss the fact that I need to compare the ID's held in the List<Guid> against the existing Proposals. So If the List<Guid> contains 1,2,3 and any of the already existing proposals contain the exact same Element-ID's I need to get a true for example.

The main goal is to avoid creation of proposals if the existing ones already contain the same elements

Comment: Isn't that what my code is doing only I'm checking an int Id rather a Guid but its the same principal?

Comment: yes in general you're right but as mentioned above I need to check against the list<guid> because the proposals should NOT be created if there is already a proposal with the exact same elements

Comment: I changed it so that its checking against a list of Ids? Does that help anymore or am I way off base?

Comment: this looks much better :) will try and give feedback :)

Comment: 2 was out of office unfortunately, but trying to implement now and will give feedback asap

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use SelectMany as I understand you correctly.. It is easier than other solutions.

```
var existingItemsWithStatusCode = existingProposals.SelectMany(s => s.GoldenRecordElements,
                    (s, p) => new { s.ProposalIdPK, s.StatusCode, p.ProposalElementIdPK })
                .Where(w => newProposals.SelectMany(s => s.GoldenRecordElements.Select(t => t.ProposalElementIdPK))
                    .Contains(w.ProposalElementIdPK)).Select(s=>new
                {
                    s.ProposalElementIdPK,s.StatusCode
                }).ToList();

var newItems = existingProposals.SelectMany(s => s.GoldenRecordElements,
                    (s, p) => new {s.ProposalIdPK, s.StatusCode, p.ProposalElementIdPK})
                .Where(w => !newProposals.SelectMany(s => s.GoldenRecordElements.Select(t => t.ProposalElementIdPK))
                    .Contains(w.ProposalElementIdPK)).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you very much. As mentioned above I need to do the check against the List<Guid> containing all new (incoming) Element-IDs. If these ID's are found in the already existing Proposals no new Proposal has to be created at all.

The suggestions actually are all checking only within the existing Proposals